# I can't replace a field after I have inherited a view

Tags: odoo

I need to use tasks functionality within my project module (i've inherited "project.project").
I've inherited "project.task" like this:

```
class task(osv.osv):
  _name = "project.task"
  _description = "Task"
  _date_name = "date_start"
  _inherit = 'project.task'
  _columns={
          'my_project_id': fields.many2one('project.my.project', 'Project'),
          }

  task()
```

Now i need to replace the project_id field from the task create form with 'my_project_id'. I did this:

```
<record id="view_task_form2_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">project.task.form</field>
        <field name="model">project.task</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
        <field eval="2" name="priority"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="project_id" position="replace">
                <field name="my_project_id"/>
            </field>

   </field>
</record>
```

And it give me this error: Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'project_id' is not defined.

Notice that if i use position="before" or "after", the "my_project_id" field is added correctly (before/after the "project_id" field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using xpath

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='project_id']" position="replace">
```

May it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source model view before replacing

use xpath to replace

in the expr use exact path where the field is defined in xml.